# How to correctly enforce field combination in another table (Django)?

Tags: django, django-models

I have `Outcode` model that has a one-to-many relationship with `SubOutcode` model:

```
class Outcode(models.Model):
    outcode = models.CharField(max_length=4, primary_key=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'outcode'
```

`SubOutcode` model:

```
class SubOutcode(models.Model):
    outcode = models.ForeignKey('Outcode', models.DO_NOTHING)
    sub_outcode = models.CharField(max_length=4, default="")

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['outcode', 'sub_outcode'], name='unq_sub_outcode')
        ]
        db_table = 'sub_outcode'
```

I want to be able to create `Property` records only if the matching combination of fields exists in `SubOutcode`. How do I setup `Property` correctly? My current setup doesn't work as it looks if `Outcode` and `SubOutcode` exist separately as per below, but I want `Property` to enforce the combination if that makes sense? Thank you for your help.

```
class Property(models.Model):     

    property_outcode = models.ForeignKey('Outcode', models.DO_NOTHING)
    property_sub_outcode = models.ForeignKey('SubOutcode', models.DO_NOTHING, to_field='sub_outcode')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code above, SubOutcode instances can only exist if they have a reference to an Outcode instance. That's because you didn't set `null=True` on the SubOutcode's foreign key.

So you could just delete property_outcode on your Property model, as its SubOutcode **must** have a foreign key pointing to an Outcode instance:

```py
class Property(models.Model):     
    property_sub_outcode = models.ForeignKey('SubOutcode', models.DO_NOTHING, to_field='sub_outcode')
```

Now your Property instances will always only exist if its reference to the SubOutcode also has a Outcode instance.

If you have a property_instance and want to know which Outcode instance its SubOutcode references, use:
`property_instance.property_sub_outcode.outcode`.